# To make a tag for a synonym tag: explanations

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, tag-synonyms

I have wanted to create for an existing [timeline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline) tag two synonyms called [chronosys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronosys) and [chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology).

Is it correct my work to create new synonyms tags or my procedure is wrong?

What should I do so that the two synonyms can be accepted?

**EDIT:** I have not very clear the explanation in this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

[image]

Comment: does not seem right to make them synonyms, timeline is a general subject area tag and the others denote specific latex packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have put into usage guidance (excerpt): To draw to graphically represent a chronological sequence of events in various fields. The tags {chronology} and {chronosys} are also compatible with this tag. After below: [tag:chronology] is explained into the site https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronology; [tag:chronosys] is explained into the site https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf. What is the best solution?

Comment: what is the problem that you want to find a solution for?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An explanation and an example to edit the tags correctly, and add new tags.

Comment: but are you not also trying to make chronology a synonym for timeline?

Comment: the tag synonym procedure is explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms